# mysql_insert_id doesn't ever seem to work

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('', ...)";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
$id = mysql_insert_id($result) or die('oops'); //mysql_error() instead of oops produces the same result
echo $id . "\nDone";
```

The table that this insert occurs on has an auto-incroment field however all that this outputs is:

> Done

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm A complete idiot, I read the manual several times and the problem never clicked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to pass $result to mysql_insert_id you should pass $link variable.

Answer (score 2):

The [`mysql_insert_id()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) expects the first parameter to be a connection resource.

Answer (score 1):

do mysql_insert_id($link) or mysql_insert_id() instead of mysql_insert_id($result) since mysql_insert_id parameter is [resource $link_identifier]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass it anything, and if you do you should be passing the connection var